# Measurable function definition - one issue

Tags: probability, measure-theory

The measurable function is defined as:

Given measurable spaces $(X, \mathcal{B}_X), (Y, \mathcal{B}_Y)$, a measurable map $f : X \to Y$ is one such that $f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{B}_X$ for $A \in \mathcal{B}_Y$. In this case, we say that $f$ is $(\mathcal{B}_X, \mathcal{B}_Y)$-measurable.

Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ is the probability space ($F$ is the set of events which is a sigma-algebra).

If $f$ is a random variable (which has to be a measurable function by definiton), then we usually take $f$ such that it is $(\mathcal{F},B(\mathbb{R}))$. Why? $B(\mathbb{R}))$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra containing Borel sets.

I understand the choice of $F$- as the $\sigma$-algebra on the sample space $\Omega$.

However, why do we take $\sigma$-algebra of the codomain to be $B(\mathbb{R})$?

If we took the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$ instead, it would most likely turn out there are fewer measurable functions we can use, because their preimages wouldn't belong to $F$? Is that the reason? And what's so special in Borel sets that they are sufficient?

You might say okay, Borel sets include all sets of practical use in real life and we can simply forget about non-Borel sets such as Vitali set for instance, because it's unlikely we would like to find probability that the random variable takes all values from Vitali set (so the random variable is $(\mathcal{F},B(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable, instead of $(\mathcal{F},\mathbb{R})$.

Does it make any sense?

I'd say the specific choice of the $\sigma$-algebra on codomain is arbitrary, and it depends solely on our needs and the specific case... right?

Comment: You can take $T=P(Y)$ so you are actually asking: "why do we not restrict to this special case?" If we do then we restrict ourselves. Random variables are demanded to give measurable preimages of Borelsets (wich e.g. comes to the same as sets of the form $(-\infty,c)$). Lots of them will fail to give measurable preimages of *all* subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @drhab I admit my question didn't make much sense, so I've corrected it.

Comment: The choice for Borelsets is for a big deal motivated by the convenience that in that case all continuous functions (w.r.t. usual topology on $\mathbb R$) are measurable. To achieve that the choice is sufficient and necessary as well.

Comment: @drhab you obviously mean the choice Borel sigma-algebra as the sigma algebra on the codomain $Y$? $f$ is $X \to Y$.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f:X\to Y$ is said to be **measurable** iff the preimage of every $Y$-measurable set is an $X$-measurable set.

$$\forall E\in \sigma(Y)\quad f^{-1}(E)\in \sigma(X)$$

A $Y$-measureable set is an element of the sigma-algebra of $Y$, here by named $T$, and *vice versa*.

This sigma algebra, $T$, is *a subset* of the power set of $Y$.

So, there *may* be sets in the power set which are not members of the sigma-algebra: which is to say that they are not $Y$-measureable.

We don't care about these.   We are only interested in **measurable** things.

Comment: What is $\sigma(Y)$ here?

Comment: Some sigma algebra of $Y$.  In this case, $T$.

Comment: Bad notation since that usually means the sigma-algebra generated by the random variable Y.

Comment: Also, I don't think this answers anything: You say we are only interested in measurable things, but being measurable depends on which sigma-algebra you put on $X$ and $Y$ in the first place. You could just equip $Y$ with the power set in which case we're interested in all subsets of $Y$.